# How to cast a google::protobuf::Message* to concrete protocol-buffer object

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Proto defined as below:

```
/*
Message Test {
    int32 a = 1;
    repeated int64 b = 2;
};
*/
```

c++ code below:

```
// msg is a `Test` type pointer
int32_t get_a(google::protobuf::Message* msg) {
    Test t1;
    // what is the most efficient way to convert `msg` to `t1`
    return t1.a();
}
```

`ParseFromString` might be too slow as far as I know.
Is reflection slow?
What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @ch271828n yeah, thx. Since in my context the `caller` knows exact type of the `Message`, so I use `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

From the official doc https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial, you can do this:

```
Test t;
t.set_a(1);
t.add_b(2);
std::string data;
t.SerializeToString(&data);

Test t1;
t1.ParseFromString(&input); // or ParseFromIstream if you have a stream
```

In other words, you can directly parse that message into your Test object.

The high-level idea is that, protobuf is *strongly typed* and make heavy use of *code generators*. So with all those auto-generated code, you can happily parse the data into your struct/class!

Comment: I'm dealing with a function passing `google::protobuf::Message* msg` as parameter.  In my context, the `msg` is of type `Test`. `ParseFromString` is probably too slow for my case.

Comment: @RoyHuang So edit your question to show your actual use-case and code, not some abridged paraphrasing of it that can mislead people.

Comment: @RoyHuang I am a bit confused. In your sample I can just ignore the `msg` (see my updated ans). Could you please give a sample showing your situation?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to `Test*`:

```
int32_t get_a(google::protobuf::Message* msg) {
    auto *t1 = dynamic_cast<Test*>(msg);
    if (t1 == nullptr)
        throw runtime_error("not of type Test");
    return t1->a();
}
```

Comment: Is `dynamic_cast` a more efficient way compared to reflection?

Comment: Yes, it can be optimized to be very fast. Check [this](https://www.stroustrup.com/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf) for example. Also if you're sure that the passed in parameter is of type `Test`, you can use `static_cast`, which is even faster than `dynamic_cast`.